# bash sed regexp replace not finding results

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file with rows that look like:

```
mv -v DF-02239.jpg DF-02239.jpg
mv -v DF-02240.jpg DF-02240.jpg
mv -v DF-02241.jpg DF-02241.jpg
mv -v DF-02242.jpg DF-02242.jpg
```

I'm trying to replace the FIRST .jpg with .JPG and am using the following sed:

```
sed 's/\(mv -v .*?\)\(\.jpg\)\(.*\)/\1.JPG \3/' finalDuplicates.txt > finalCaseDuplicates.txt
```

I have verified the regexp works here: 
http://regex101.com/r/cU9xV2/1

Comment: Is there a reason for which you don't want to simply use `sed 's/jpg /JPG /'`? the first JPGs have a following space, the second ones don't, so you could take advantage of that

Comment: seriously?! Okay. Let me try. That's way simpler. If that doesn't work... do you see anything wrong with my regexp? I'll keep you posted... one moment

Comment: @morgano please post as an answer and I'll credit you.

Comment: One thing that is wrong in your pattern is the use of a non-greedy quantifier that doesn't exist in the default mode (basic regex engine) of sed.

Comment: actually, it didn't work when I added >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply replace the jpg to JPG , `sed` replace the first occurrence only

```
sed 's/jpg/JPG/' file_name
```

**output**

```
mv -v DF-02239.JPG DF-02239.jpg
mv -v DF-02240.JPG DF-02240.jpg
mv -v DF-02241.JPG DF-02241.jpg
mv -v DF-02242.JPG DF-02242.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your syntax just a bit:

```
sed 's/\(mv -v .*\.\)jpg\(.*jpg\)/\1JPG\2/'
```

The trick is to involve second `jpg` string into equation, so that greedy `sed` doesn't match the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the following regex which uses a negated character class.

```
sed 's/^\(mv -v[^.]\+\.\)jpg/\1JPG/'
```

<kbd>[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/EB1GAW)</kbd>